# Why is the scrollbar not selectable when the cursor is at the edge of the screen?

Tags: css

I've created a simplified version of our application's layout:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.pageLayout {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.pageLayout__pageMenuColumn {
  background-color: blue;
}

.pageLayout__pageMenuColumn {
  max-width: 330px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pageLayout__pageMenuColumnWrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pageLayout__pageColumn {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.pageLayout__PageColumnContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div className="app">
  <section class="pageLayout">
    <aside class="pageLayout__pageMenuColumn">
    </aside>
    <div class="pageLayout__pageMenuColumnWrapper">
      <section class="pageLayout__pageColumn">
        <div class="pageLayout__PageColumnContent">
          <div class="searchResultsPanel">
            <div class="searchContents">
              <ul>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>Hello</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

See on CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/tommcandrew/pen/XWjwQWE?editors=1100).

Video [here](https://nimbusweb.me/s/share/5122731/oluhhe4hvz6cqcaq6plg).

If I move the cursor to the very right edge of the screen, the scrollbar isn't selectable. Can anyone tell me why this is? It's been driving me mad!

I've noticed that if you remove the aside element on the left of the screen (with the blue background), the problem is gone. That might be a clue but I haven't been able to figure it out. I've also noticed that I have the problem on Chrome and Edge but not Firefox.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce your issue when I move the cursor to the right edge. I tested on both `firefox` and `chrome` latest version browsers. it works without any problem.

Comment: can you add a picture pointing to the problem ? in this example its working fine but try to remove the overflows

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I've added a link to a screen capture so you can see what I'm talking about. Problem doesn't seem to be on Firefox. Removing the overflow: auto on pageLayout__PageColumnContent does solve the scrollbar issue but I do need that element to be scrollable.